# Working through a very basic Sinatra web app, can’t get all the HTML code to show in browser

Tags: html, sinatra, eruby

I’m working on a Sinatra app. Part of the code will show up in the browser while the other part will not and I can’t figure out why.

```
<h1>Welcome <%=@user.username%>!</h1>
<h2>Your Clients:</h2>

<%if @user.clients.empty?%>
  <h3> You have no clients. Add a client using the link below.</h3>
  <h2><a href="/clients/new">Add Client</a></h2>

<% else %>
  <% @clients.each do |client| %>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/clients/<%=client.id%>"><%= client.name %></a></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`<h1>` and `<h2>` at the top of the page show in the browser but nothing else will.

Comment: If you View Source on your page (Ctrl+U), what HTML shows up? Note that `@user.clients` and `@clients` are different, so it may be that the `else` is reached but no `<ul>`s are rendered.

Comment: only the <h1> and <h2> show up on the Source code for HTML

Comment: So… did you mean `@user.clients`?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `@user.clients` is empty. But you are looping over `@clients`. Chance is that they do not have the same content. You should loop over the same variable as you use in your if statement.